# Using Data Validation Lists and VLOOKUP to Link Two Cells

Tags: excel

I have an order form I'm working on that I would like to be slightly automated. There is an "Part Number" column and an "Item Description" column on the form. I would like to turn all cells under these two columns into drop-down lists. That way, when you click on a cell in the "Part Number" column, you're provided with a list of part numbers to choose from, and the same goes for the description. This is simple enough and is easily accomplished using Data Validation lists.

The problem is that I want to link the two columns so that filling in either cell on a row via drop-down list will populate the other cell with the appropriate information. (i.e. The user fills in the "Part Number" cell and the "Description" cell gets populated. Or, the user fills in the "Description" cell and the "Part Number" cell get populated.)

I know I can get halfway there with VLOOKUP; I can make one of the columns have the drop-down list selection and the other column has the VLOOKUP formula. But I can't have Data Validation on a cell with a formula, so I can't put VLOOKUP in both columns. (This would probably end up creating an endless loop anyway.) Any suggestions on making this work with the cells in both columns?

Comment: You will need vba using the Worksheet_Change event.

Comment: How about having multiple columns, containing the same data. For example column A would have the `Part Number` information, and column B would have `=$A1` in all the cells.  Then, your VLOOKUP for the `Item Description` references column A, and the dropdown refers to column B.  Do the same with columns C and D for the `Part Number` information.